# How can I insert pictures in home page that when I click on them it goes to a specific page?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to insert pictures on my home page in SharePoint server.

when someone clicks on them, it should redirect user to another page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to achieve this:

1. Create one new list using "Promoted Links" template.
2. Add the list web part of that promoted link list on your home page.

Use following links for more clarification:

1. [Use Promoted Links List](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-add-sharepoint-tiles-promoted-links-to-your-site/).
2. [Add List Web part](http://www.isacantx.org/SharePointTraining/TrainingPages/ListView.html).
3. [How to add list web part on a page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28537f90-5c3c-47dc-920b-3ce91d6547f1/how-to-add-a-list-view-webpart-to-a-page-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointadmin).

Comment: Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

For OOB function, you could use Promoted link list.

You could use JS library like [bxslider](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4) also.

You could check my test demo [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/839ccbd5-2031-476f-85d0-fc2e5fbb8710/slider-menu-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointdevelopment).

Answer (score 0):

Very simple Method :
1-Add a content Editor webpart.
2- in this webpart insert the image
4-Click on the picture and in the link tab add the link where you want to redirect

That's all :)
**if you want it responsive you can make it in a table and make the design layout of the table to clear